# How do I search through all the parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently searching by name only. In addition, large and small letters are taken into account. How do I search in all the parameters of the user? and without taking into account the big and small letters?

I have the following options: `lastName`, `company`, `title`, `email`, `phone`, `street`, `city`, `country`.

```
dispatch => ({
    onFindPeople: (firstName) => {
        console.log(firstName);
        dispatch({ type: 'FIND_PEOPLE', payload: firstName})
    }
})
```

I added a sample code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7oxkkpqoj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
const isMatch = (user, filter) =>
  new RegExp(filter, "i").test(JSON.stringify(user));

state.allPeople.filter(user => isMatch(user, state.filterPeople));
```

Comment: @max if that helped don't forget to mark answer as correct

Comment: Thank you. Could you please describe what exactly you did in these 3 lines, so I could figure it out?

Comment: ^ I agree with that. @MohammedEssehemy, when you provide an answer you should explain what your code suggests and does. This is helpful for the owner to the question and other people who will see this answer in the future.

Comment: For the time being, here is a simple explanation @max. This code filters your array, then for each user (which is an object) sends it to the `isMatch` test function for the `.filter` method. `isMatch` first [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your user object.

Comment: Then it uses [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to search the string. This returns `true` or `false`, so the `filter` method returns the related user or users.

Comment: @devserkan I agree with you, I just was in a hurry.